# what is Authorization: < Standard OAuth credentials >

Tags: c#, oauth, yahoo-api, yahoo-messenger

what is `Authorization: < Standard OAuth credentials >` ? and how can I send it by a post method in C# ?

I do have the  `OAuth` access token which is a string as such

```
oauth_token=A%3Dvh....aRg--&oauth_token_secret=bd46a....c9239&oauth_expires_in=3600&oauth_session_handle=ALtT.....3J1N4Zg--&oauth_authorization_expires_in=784964948&xoauth_yahoo_guid=TUSKED5...NCIA
```

Answer (score 0):

This particular guide may assist you, he goes into great detail and explains each process with a lot of [detail](http://www.deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/a-simple-guide-to-using-oauth-with-c-/49). The details are to use it with sites such as:

- Twitter
- Twitpic
- Facebook
- Flickr
- Etc

But it goes into detail of utilizing the token you receive and physically linking your application so your properly utilizing those OAuth Request.

I'm not sure if I misunderstood you and you aren't using such an API, if you can clarify I'd be happy to try and assist you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Greg. I am trying to integrate with Yahoo messenger which requires OAuth. I managed to get the request token and then using that i got the access token. Now i need to send messages and for that the POST method requires OAuth.

Comment: Then that post may actually go into the right detail for you.

Comment: It has for twitter. I downloaded the OAuth Manager but the dll file seems to have stuff for twitter only and not for yahoo

Comment: I believe the example utilizes Sound Studio or something physically on the page.